# Mouse automation software for macOS that's still maintained?

Tags: automation, mouse, macos, macos-mojave

Over the years I found Murgaa.com's mouse automation tool to be very useful, however their support has seemed to disappear over the last year or two. I'm looking for a mouse automation tool that's still maintained and well supported in Mojave+. Are there any such little software creatures?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Sikuli](http://sikulix.com/).

I a Python framework for:

- daily usage of applications or web pages
- playing games
- administration of IT systems and networks

Watch [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VdCOg1bCmGo) to see how it works

Answer (score 1):

I've found that Keyboard Maestro is fitting the bill for this. It's a bit more involved to configure, but working rather well. Has some quirky issues itself in Mojave, but overall it works.